# Access Activity below in the stack

Tags: android

I have pushed one Activity to make few changes. Now I want to pass all the changes to the previous(below) Activity. I dont want to create Activity again;and intead i want to access the previous activity.

thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Use `startActivityForResult()` and `setResult()`. The former is used to start the newer activity; the latter is used to pass results back to the older activity.